# stack does not resolve dependencies when installing hip

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

I want to install the Haskell libary hip from https://hackage.haskell.org/package/hip by using stack. This does not work, because stack seems to not being able to install dependencies.

I have stack freshly installed by `curl -sSL https://get.haskellstack.org/ | sh`, and `stack --version` gives me

`Version 1.9.3, Git revision 40cf7b37526b86d1676da82167ea8758a854953b (6211 commits) x86_64 hpack-0.31.1`

I have tried several things like another resolver, reinstalling different versions of stack, ghc or cabal.

I have tried `stack new test`, and inside the `test` folder, i wrote `stack install hip`.

I got the following error:

```
Error: While constructing the build plan, the following exceptions were
encountered:

In the dependencies for hip-1.5.3.0:
    Chart must match >=1.5, but the stack configuration has no specified
          version  (latest matching version is 1.9)
    Chart-diagrams must match >=1.5, but the stack configuration has no
                   specified version  (latest matching version is 1.9)
needed since hip is a build target.

Some different approaches to resolving this:

  * Consider trying 'stack solver', which uses the cabal-install solver to
    attempt to find some working build configuration. This can be convenient
    when dealing with many complicated constraint errors, but results may be
    unpredictable.

  * Recommended action: try adding the following to your extra-deps
    in /home/jarek/Desktop/test/stack.yaml:

Chart-1.9@sha256:f41568b6b3704f66c2ec163295b430ab7d798f91de426c2d5aba747d1135cd9b
Chart-diagrams-1.9@sha256:cdd0c22d730e507f9644e690833096ee127302b5ff5e1571f6def419160a2642

Plan construction failed.
```

I expect something like:

```
Building dependencies...
Installing Chart-1.9
...
...
...
hip successfully installed.
```

Please tell me if i did not provide all infos necessary for you to help me with my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Why not do what `stack` recommended?

```
Recommended action: try adding the following to your extra-deps
in /home/jarek/Desktop/test/stack.yaml:

Chart-1.9@sha256:f41568b6b3704f66c2ec163295b430ab7d798f91de426c2d5aba747d1135cd9b
Chart-diagrams-1.9@sha256:cdd0c22d730e507f9644e690833096ee127302b5ff5e1571f6def419160a
```

It's the easiest way to accomplish your goal.

**Update:** `lts-10.10` is the most recent resolver to include hip.  If you update your `stack.yaml` to use `lts-10.10` and add `hip` in your `.cabal` file, you should be good to go.

Comment: These packages are present in hackage, so it should work without adding to `extra-deps` in my understanding. Also adding these leads the same error, and the recommendation is `Recommended action: try adding the following to your extra-deps
    in /home/jarek/Desktop/lolol/stack.yaml:

SVGFonts-1.6.0.3@sha256:...
containers-0.5.11.0@sha256:...
diagrams-postscript-1.4.1@sha256:...
lens-4.16.1@sha256:...`

Answer (score 0):

Installing with the resolver `lts-7.5` works.

Comment: This leads to another question: how can i find the newest resolver, which includes a certain package i want to install?

Comment: One question at a time please. Post follow-up questions separately.