# How can i find a stack resolver that contains my package?

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

Trying to install hip with the newest stack resolver (lts-13.4) does not work (see my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54296951/stack-does-not-resolve-dependencies-when-installing-hip/)), because dependencies are not in hackage. However, installing with resolver lts-7.5 does work. How can i find out which resolver can install a specific package?

Answer (score 2):

It does not seem to be very well advertised on stackage, but one can obtain the list of all the snapshots a package appears in using an URL like the following one.

https://www.stackage.org/package/hip/snapshots

How did I find that URL? I browsed an old enough LTS which contained `hip`. Then I browsed the `hip` package page within that snapshot. There, I found a link named "[See all snapshots `hip` appears in](https://www.stackage.org/package/hip/snapshots)".

Answer (score 1):

I answered this in your previous question, `https://www.stackage.org/package/THE_PACKAGE_NAME`